# How to change size of a layout inside ScrollView?

Tags: java, android

I have a custom View that is nested inside ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView>
    <ScrollView>
        <GameView>
        </GameView>
    </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I want to change the GameView size depending on user action (zooming in or out) but when I try to do

```
gameView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((int)(gameView.BOARD_WIDTH * gameView.STEP), (int)(gameView.BOARD_HEIGHT * gameView.STEP)));
```

I get an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams

at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1066)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:296)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(HorizontalScrollView.java:1075)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onMeasure(HorizontalScrollView.java:302)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there a way of changing the size of the gameView?

Edit: I have solved the issue, the anwser was:

```
gameView.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams((int)(BOARD_WIDTH * STEP), (int)(BOARD_HEIGHT * STEP)));
```

Comment: I have solved the issue, the solution was using LayoutParams of the parent View:

Comment: Add you answer and set it to removed the question from the unanswered list. Good that you were able to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, the solution was using LayoutParams of the parent View:

```
gameView.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams((int)(BOARD_WIDTH * STEP), (int)(BOARD_HEIGHT * STEP)));
```